# Updating belief

Tags: bayes

Lets say I think that event 'E' has a probability 'p' of happening. Then I go around and ask a number of friends if they think event 'E' will happen, they can either answer Yes or No. Now I know that a number of my friends a more or (unfortunately) less knowledgeable about the subject, lets say I can divide them in a number of levels.

By how much should I then update my belief (i.e. the probability) of event 'E' happening, given the opinions of my friends and their knowledge level? I have done a few calculations using Bayes Rule and I am able to generate weights per Level. But this approach seems to trivial. And I'm also looking for a way to generate confidence/credibility intervals.

What changes when I want to use an additive model instead of a multiplicative one?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You update belief with data. In this case you have no new data on the probability of the event. There nothing to update with. You are thinking of the way to update your belief with *beliefs* of your friends and your beliefs about their knowledge of the subject. It's beliefs on belief on beliefs... Whatever you come up with is going to be as good as anything in the absence of *data*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this easier to discuss, I'm going to rephrase the problem:

- A coin is flipped, which we encode as a random variable $z \in \{1, 0\}$. Your prior probability of it being heads is $p(z = 1) = \theta$.
- Your friends $j \in 1, \dotsc, D$ see the coin and tell you what it is, which we encode as a random variable $y_j \in \{1, 0\}$. For simplicity, we're going to assume these $y_j$ are independent when conditioned on $z$.
- Friend $j$ will give you honest answer $\phi_j \in [0,1]$ of the time.

Since the $y_j$ are independent when conditioned on $z$, when the coin is heads the likelihood is

$$p(y|z=1) = \prod_j p(y_i|z=1) = \prod_j \phi_j^{y_j}(1-\phi_j)^{1-y_j} $$

So by Bayes' rule the posterior probability of heads is

$$p(z=1|y) \propto p(y|z=1)p(z=1) = \theta \prod_j \phi_j^{y_j}(1-\phi_j)^{1-y_j}$$

Having built the model this far, there's two things you could do next:

- Change the $\phi_j$ from constants to random variables, allowing you to model your uncertainty in the trustworthiness of your friends.
- Relax the indpedendence assumptions on the $y_j$, allowing you to model collusion amongst your friends.

In either case, if you want to take it further you'll probably want to do some reading on "graphical models".